# Jquery Ajax Request Not Sending Post Data

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, post, knockout.js

I'm successfully making an AJAX call with the Jquery `$.ajax` method, in that the file it's POSTing to is getting called and executing. However, no POST data is being sent. All I want to do is send the data and have it received by the file; I don't care about returning data.

I've tried changing it to GET, which didn't yield results. I passed GET data in the URL which was received (obviously, I guess). I've also tried changing the data type that I'm sending...none of this has given me any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong. I've also browsed the numerous questions here with similar titles, but nothing seemed to fix this issue. Though I'm sure it's something simple.

Other variables that may be relevant: I'm using Knockout JS. I'm using .htaccess redirects to create a single point of entry in a /public folder.

And without further ado, here's the code:

### page.html

```
<button data-bind="click: save">Save</button>
```

If you're unfamiliar with KOJS, it basically just calls the function save when you click it. I'm pretty sure this is working properly.

### models.js

```
self.save = function() {
    var jsonData = ko.toJSON(self.tasks);
    $.ajax("http://test.local.com/js/post.php", {
        data: jsonData,
        type: "post", contentType: "application/json",
        success: function(result) { alert(jsonData) }
    });
};
```

That alert is giving me a nicely formatted JSON object, like

```
[{"title": "Clean up the dog"},{"title": "Warm up the old pasta"}]
```

It's the post file, I think, where my error is? The $_POST array is empty. And if I change it to send as GET, that's also empty. I put comments in the code explaining things.

### post.php

```
if (isset($_POST)) {
  //It does get inside this if. That's good at least, right?

  $my_file = 'file.txt';
  $handle = fopen($my_file, 'w') or die('Cannot open file:  '.$my_file);
  //It will make this file.

  fwrite($handle, print_r($_POST));
  //Prints "1" without the quotes


  foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
    fwrite($handle, 'your data: '.$value.'; ');
  }
  //Prints nothing
}
```

Any thoughts as to why this won't send any POST data? I'm sure it's something silly. Thanks!

Comment: You do realize that you are alerting the same data that you are sending, and not the data you are receiving? As a sidenote the console would probably be more suited to read JSON than an alert.

Comment: Yeah, I do. I did what I knew how to do, which is make sure that I've at least properly prepared the data to send over. If I thought that I wasn't sending data at all, then this question would have been worded entirely differently, I think!

Comment: Open up the network panel in the dev tools of your browser of choice, and check that you can see the request being sent. Before you even consider what's happening server-side, ensure that it's even sending!

Comment: You're not returning anything from the PHP file at all, are you expecting data back ?

Comment: In your php code, if you want print_r to return instead of print you must use second parameter TRUE.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php

Comment: I'm not expecting data back. I just want to send data via post to a file. I edited the question to explicitly state this.

Comment: @WickyNilliams, it does seem to be sending from the page! Maybe my .htaccess redirects are messing with it somehow? I'm not sure if that's a possibility, though :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your issue is that you're setting `data` as a JSON string. Per the docs jQuery won't process string data, only objects http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Instead use `ko.toJS` to get a clean JS object and that should get you going in the right path.

[edit]

I just noticed you were setting the contentType as well... For that to work you won't be able to use the `$_POST` var. Instead you'll need to grab the data from `file_get_contents("php://input")` that "should" give you the raw JSON string. From there you should be able to use PHP's `json_decode` to turn it into a true PHP object.

Comment: Your first suggestion seems to have solved one of the issues, but it still isn't working. I got rid of the contentType attribute, changed it to `ko.toJS`, and passed that object over. That made my $_POST have a count() of 1, but the key was 'undefined' and the value empty. Setting processData: false makes the count() of $_POST return to 0.

Comment: hmm... maybe go back to the contentType: application/json but note that you wont find the data in php's `$_POST`. I'll update my answer

Comment: Brilliance. Using `$jsondata = file_get_contents("php://input");` and `fwrite($handle, $jsondata);` prints out the data! Thanks!